# How to keep imagebutton in pressed state and display the drawable for pressed state

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/vopressed" /> //light blue
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/voselected" /> //blue
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/vo" /> //black
</selector>
```

XML:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/vo_selector"
        android:id="@+id/ibS"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

I am trying to change to light blue on click and dark blue after.

```
ibS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ibS.setPressed(true);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

How can I make it so when I click on it, it stays on the pressed/selected state and the drawable change from black to blue and when I click on it again it unpresses/unselects itself and change back to black.

Comment: is ibS your image button?

Comment: I see logic error here, because inside OnClickListener you set your image button pressed state to true, but as soon as you remove your finger from the button, the pressed state will be false automatically

Comment: Yes... Any idea how to put pressed state once clicked and unpressed if clicked again and so forth...

Comment: as my answer below, you should keep your state by yourself directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with selected state of the drawable ::

```
ibS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ibS.setPressed(true);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}});
```

Change the line `ibS.setPressed(true);` to `ibS.setSelected(!ibs.isSelected());`

So, it will change the drawble of image to the selected_state image define  in the drawable the putting the state selected too..on clicking again..it will revert the last state...
Try this..

Comment: Most of the other answers works, except this one "works" with what I already have. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use button instead of Image Button as in that case you will be required with two image assets.

Use drawable :

Button unpressed state :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <padding android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

Button pressed state :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    <padding android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</shape>
```

Now set this above drawable when in need.

Comment: The drawavles are svg drawables

Comment: Thank you for the answer, regardless :)

Answer (score 1):

When you remove your finger from the button, the pressed state will always reset to `false`, so you can't use that state.
You should track your state directly by declaring member variable

```
private boolean isPressed = false;
```

Then you set the background of the image button directly when the button clicked

```
ibS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        isPressed = !isPressed;
        if (isPressed) {
            ibS.setBackgroundColor(R.color.your_blue_color);
            //use code below if you want to use drawable background
            //ibS.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_pressed);
        } else {
            ibS.setBackgroundColor(R.color.your_black_color);
            //use code below if you want to use drawable background
            //ibS.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_normal);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ibS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          ibS.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(your Context,R.drawable.voselected));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: How can i swap between the two between each click?